# VBA ComboBox Value by Index

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I've got a form that contains a combobox which contains the values

```
With io6
   .AddItem "90°"
   .AddItem "180°"
   .AddItem "270°"
   .AddItem "360°"
End With
```

The member of this method I am actually using is .ListIndex.  When a user selects 270 degrees, I am sending a 2 to a variable.  When I read the variable, I want have the combobox correctly show the appropriate value.  In other words, if the variable is 1, I want the combo box to show 180 degrees.  Is that achievable *without* a select\if statement that writes into .Value?

```
Sub varChange(val as integer)

   With comboBox

     Select Case val
       Case 1
         .value = "90°"
       Case 2
         .value = "180°"
       Case 3
         .value = "270°"
       Case 4
         .value = "360°"
     End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

The most direct I can ask this question is, can the method element be set based on the index?  Can I set the combo box element based on the index rather than having to write in a new value?

Comment: `.Value = ((.ListIndex + 1)*90)` ?

Comment: No, my question is being misunderstood.  See example of current execution.

Comment: `myCombo.ListIndex = idx`; did you get a problem with this?

Comment: This is not what I am asking.  I know that `.ListIndex` provides the index of the item selected.  What I want is to set the item selected by providing the index.

Comment: The statement I suggested above does not *provide the index of the item selected*; it rather *sets* the combo by providing some index `idx`*.

Comment: i just created a combo box in excel, `input range: A1:A4` . `call link: B1` . A1:A4 has the four values in your example. ... select 270 in combo box ... B1 changes to 3 ... combo box shows 270 ... enter 4 into B1 ... combo box changes to 360 ....... is that how you want the combo box to behave with VBA control?

Comment: Yep, that sounds like it.  Except I'm doing it in an MSForm, but it's probably the same.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I got it right, but I think you want to get the list index of the selected item.
You can get that by

```
x = io6.ListIndex + 1
```

The +1 is there since ListIndex is 0 based, but you wanted it 1 based.
And something completely different,
Remove the brackets. Method calls without return values does not use them in VBA

**Edit after comment**
To take this the other way, i.e getting a value from an index value, do like this:

```
y = io6.List(x - 1)
```

Comment: No.  I guess I need to be more clear.  I want to show the combobox value based on the variable.  In other words, if variable = 1, I want to show the combobox value who's listindex is = 1.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort, but that's still not right.  In fact, that wouldn't work at all.  The `.List` property is used for creating list items from an array.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/list-property-microsoft-forms says "Returns or sets the list entries of a ListBox or ComboBox"

Answer (score 0):

`sValue = combobox.List(combobox.ListIndex,0)`

Comment: I think adding explanation about your solution would be necessary.

Comment: There isnt much to explain... combobox is the name of the combobox, and the .List property is how you get data out of the combobox, specifying the ListIndex as the row argument, and 0 for the column argument. that will return the value in the first column of the selected item to the sValue variable. In this case, there is only one column in the combobox.

Comment: I know all of these. But even editing and adding a line and maybe a link to documentation would make your answer to not show up in the low quality post queue.

Comment: This is where you and everyone else seems to be getting it wrong.  I'm not trying to get data out.  I'm trying to change what data is displayed based on an index variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can do the reverse as well... `combobox.List(combobox.ListIndex,0)="New Value"`

Answer (score 0):

> The most direct I can ask this question is, can the method element be set based on the index? Can I set the combo box element based on the index rather than having to write in a new value?

Yes,
I used the following line:

```
io6.ListIndex = val - 1
```

So in your code it's:

```
Sub varChange(val as integer)
    comboBox.ListIndex = val - 1
End Sub
```